# UPDATE & DELETE multiple rows with an array for the id

Tags: php, mysql

I wan't to check for challenges a user's team posted that have not been excepted after 1 day, then auto refund the user's team back there credits, and then also delete all the challenges. So far here is my code.

```
//Delete all matches not accepted after 1 day
$arrayin = array();
$autorefund = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `challenges` WHERE `a` = " . $team['id'] . " "
        . "AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 AND (`expires` < " . ((int) time()) . ")");
if (mysql_num_rows($autorefund) > 0) {
    while ($autorefund = mysql_fetch_assoc($autorefund)) {
        $arrayin[] = $autorefund['id'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE `teams` SET `balance` =  `balance` + " . $autorefund['credits'] . " "
                . "WHERE `id` IN (" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $arrayin)) . ")");
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `challenges` WHERE `a` IN "
                . "(" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $arrayin)) . ") "
                . "AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 "
                . "AND (`expires` < " . ((int) time()) . ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get this fixed you should look into using [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). Just a tip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM challenges
WHERE `a` = {$team['id']} AND accepted = 0 AND completed = 0 AND chtype = 1 AND expires < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";

$result = mysql_query($query);


if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
   $arrayin = array(); 
while($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

mysql_query("UPDATE teams SET balance = balance + {$row['credits']} WHERE id = {$row['a']}");
   $arrayin[] = $row['id']; 
}

mysql_query("DELETE FROM challenges WHERE id IN(".implode(',',$arrayin).")");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the MySQL updated, delete conditions out of the loop.

You are already getting the ids in the loop.

So, the final code should be:

```
 //Delete all matches not accepted after 1 day
    $arrayin              = array();
    $autorefund   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `challenges` WHERE `a` = " . $team['id'] . " AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 AND (`expires` < ".((int)time()).")");
    if (mysql_num_rows($autorefund) > 0) {
        while ($autorefund  = mysql_fetch_assoc($autorefund)) {
             $arrayin[] = $autorefund['id'];
        }
    }
mysql_query("UPDATE `teams` SET `balance` =  `balance` + " . $autorefund['credits'] . " WHERE `id` IN (" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $arrayin)) . ")");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `challenges` WHERE `a` IN (" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $arrayin)) . ") AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 AND (`expires` < ".((int)time()).")");
```

**Don't use mysql_ functions as they are deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP.**

Comment: I inherited this script, was built awhile ago, it has hundreds of mysql_functions, im not skilled enough to rewrite the whole site to prepared statements or PDO yet :( I tried what you did and still nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to move ids around (fetching ids with select to the client code and then creating queries with `IN` clause) you can do update and delete in one go with the proper SQL. Something along the lines of:

```php
$now = time();

mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$sql = "
UPDATE teams t JOIN challenges c
    ON t.id = c.id
   SET t.balance = t.balance + c.credits
 WHERE c.a = %d  
   AND c.accepted = 0 
   AND c.completed = 0 
   AND c.chtype = 1 
   AND c.expires < %d";
$sql = sprintf($sql, $team['id'], $now);
$update = mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "
DELETE 
  FROM challenges   
 WHERE a = %d  
   AND accepted = 0 
   AND completed = 0 
   AND chtype = 1 
   AND expires < %d";
$sql = sprintf($sql, $team['id'], $now);
$delete = mysql_query($sql);

if ($update && $delete) {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
} else {
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
```

Comment: thank you, the challenges were deleted successfully, but the team didnt recieve the credits back to there team, let me try one more thing you might be right.

Comment: yes, only problem is the credits are not being sent back to the team

Comment: I made 2 challenges for $5,000 credits each, set the expires date to the past, ran your code, and it gave $5,000 credits to another team in the table but the other $5,000 disappeared, nobody got the other half.

Comment: On the UPDATE statement I changed this line ON t.id = c.id  to ON t.id = c.a , the correct team now gets the credits, but they only recieve credits for the first challenge, if he has multiple challenges, it should sum the credits column for all challenges, how would i do that?

Comment: @marxizmmarxizm If you want more help on your question please post actual table schemas (or at least relevant parts), provide sample data and desired result in tabular form. The best way to do it is to create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Unfortunately, there is no time to deduce all the details out of your code.

Answer (score 0):

$arrayin = array();

$autorefund = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `challenges` WHERE `a` = " . $team['id'] . " "
        . "AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 AND (`expires` < " . ((int) time()) . ")");

if (mysql_num_rows($autorefund) > 0) {

```
while ($autorefund = mysql_fetch_assoc($autorefund)) {

    $arrayin[] = $autorefund['id'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE `teams` SET `balance` =  `balance` + " . $autorefund['credits']. " WHERE `id`='".$autorefund['id']."'");
 }
     mysql_query("DELETE FROM `challenges` WHERE `id` IN "
            . "(" . mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $arrayin)) . ") "
            . "AND  `accepted` = 0 AND `completed` = 0 AND `chtype` = 1 "
            . "AND (`expires` < " . ((int) time()) . ")");
```

}

Comment: It deleted the challenges but the credits did not get added, i think i might be able to modify this by getting the sum and adding that back in, hmm let me see

Comment: changed WHERE `id`='".$autorefund['id']."' to WHERE `id`='".$autorefund['a']."'  , it works, but i have to refresh the page per every challenge they have, so for example if they have 5 pending matches, page would need to be refreshed 5 times, any way around this?